# Relational database in unrelational manner

Tags: postgresql, nosql, key-value

What is pros and cons of using relational databases in noSQL manner?

Saying noSQL I mean key-value storage with some rather simple query language and horizontal scaling.

Now I'm carry out simple experiment, where postgreSQL database designed and queried in key-value manner. 
Here is example. Let it be User and Article, one-to-many in relational model.

Relational:

```
User              Article
| id | login |    | id | user_id | title |
|----+-------|    |----+---------+-------|
|  1 | Alex  |    |  1 |    1    | FooBar| 
|  2 | Ann   |    |  2 |    1    | GoGoGo|
--------------    ------------------------
and some constraints on user id
```

To fetch all user's articles we need some kind of join.

Key-value style:

```
User                          Article
| id | login | articles |    | id | user_id | title |
|----|-------|----------|    |----+---------+-------|
|  1 | Alex  |  1, 2    |    |  1 |    1    | FooBar| 
|  2 | Ann   |          |    |  2 |    1    | GoGoGo|
-------------------------    ------------------------
```

let User.articles be array, for example, postgreSQL have  some tools for working with arrays.

In this case I am going to make User's query at first, and then, when getting articles ids select them all. I think this is very similar to MongdDB's way with collections.

Moreover, I know, that second case is something, that my university tutor never says to do, but looks like this approach very-very-very scalable.

It looks like wheel reinventing, but main goal is to provide scalable solution for some promising project which now using postgres.

Comment: Storing comma separated values is **not** scalable at all. And as you store the user_id within the article table anyway. That information is redundant in the user table.

Comment: Storing data in such manner, as I suppose make sharding very simple. For example if Article table distributed through some servers I need to do only one query to User's table for getting all its articles. No joins.

Comment: You discuss the model of a 1:n relationship. But the relationship between "user" and "article" would normally be an n:m relationship?

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter, in case of this example, I haven't mean it. But generally say: yes, there are could be m:n relationships to. Moreover, I still wonder how to implement, for example User to User m:n relationship, which could be friendship relationship in case if it will be 100 000+ of users. I don't believe that such link table will be join-ed in adequate time. So this is the reason of array in articles in second case.

Comment: With proper indexes in place, even millions of rows are hardly a problem for performance. Indexes are the key here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would go with the normalized model for an n:m relationship. If, after creating **proper indexes**, `SELECT` performance is still not good enough, I would probably create **materialized views** that are updated automatically by triggers.

In such a materialized view all related IDs could be aggregated to an array - or whatever you actually need. I'd rather not use that as primary data model, though.